# Как  сделать форму оправки e-mail?

Tags: html

Нужно только используя html и mailto сделать так: на странице одна многострочная форма ввода и кнопка, по нажатии которой текст из формы должен отправиться на заданный e-mail.

---

Ещё: есть три формы для регистрации: "имя", "информация", "e-mail". И ещё кнопка. При нажатии кнопки на заданное мыло должно оправиться письмо с содержимым этих полей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<FORM Action="mailto:xyz" METHOD="POST" ENCTYPE="text/plain">
    mailto: protocol test:
    <Br>Subject: 
    <INPUT name="Subject" value="Test Subject">
    <Br>Body:&#xa0;
    <TEXTAREA name="Body">
    123
    </TEXTAREA>
    <BR>
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</FORM>
```

Comment: Так все равно Outlook вызывается )

Comment: На js не сделаешь. Надо использовать в таком случае серверные средства. JS **клиентское** средство и возможен только такой исход.

Comment: Это понятно что серверными средствами надо делать такое, но можно ведь с простой гиперссылки вызвать.

Comment: @gold а кто сказал что мне нужен не Outlook? Я спрашивал о другом - как описать тело письма

Comment: @gold я писал "текст из ФОРМЫ должен отправиться", т.е. чтобы открылся outlook  а в нём уже был набран текст

Comment: @stck, спасибо, но только при нажатии sumbit в oulook'e вместо текста какие-то крякозябры. Что-то с кодировкой. что делать? или это уже проблему оутлука?

Comment: http://rghost.ru/41193739/image.png

Comment: @ололо, не видел вашего комментария, да, раз так то это проблема отлука

Answer (score 1):

В любом случае будет вызываться почтовый клиент по умолчанию. С помощью JS возможно изменение href параметра ссылки.

```
<a href="mailto:test@mail.com?Subject=testsubject&Body=testbody">SEND</a>
```

Для отправки email необходим почтовый сервер (или хороший серверный скрипт с блекджеком и сокетами). С помощью браузерного JS отправка email без ведома клиента не производится.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="mailto:e@mail"><textarea></textarea><input type="sumbit"></form>
```

Comment: И?
где кнопка?

Comment: Добавь <input type="button" value="Отправить" /> и будет тебе кнопка.

Comment: Да, но в письме не видно содержимого  тексареа

Comment: Это понятно что не видно ) Не сильно опытен , но думаю Вам нужно копать в сторону SMTP и POP3 вроде  )

Comment: @gold, хм мне дали задание только используя html и минимум js сделать такую штуку. Неужели это неозможно? :(

Comment: Можно почему же , Outlook настроить,и когда <a href="mailto:test@test.ru">Отправить письмо</a> откроется Outlook , и с него написать.